# Does placement in the tile/card pattern affect the number of clicks on the tile?

Tags: website-design, usability, design-patterns

I’m looking for data on the popular Pinterest-like grid designs. I’m wondering --
Does placement in the grid affect the number of clicks on the tile (as evidenced by Google Analytics or other concrete metrics)?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is a correlation between tile placement and number of clicks, although I do not have any true data to support this.

Just like any other content, depending on the language of your users, they will most likely view content in specific pattern. In English, Left to Right, Top to bottom. Depending on the content of your tiles, the longer time it takes for me to reach the bottom right corner of the screen, the increased chance of me finding content along the way and resulting in me clicking a tile and leaving this tile grid.

Again, just my thoughts.